# Parse JSON response and append the values to div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have data like this in `JSON.parse(response);`:

```
{
    "booking_trip": {
        "no_of_traveler": "2",
        "pack_stat_date": "02\/20\/2017",
        "pack_final_date": "02\/27\/2017",
        "package_details_id": "273",
        "promo_discount": "",
        "discount": ""
    },
    "price": "5000"
}
```

How can I append these values to a particular div?

Comment: show your html too

Comment: What kind of output are you expecting? There's an infinite number of ways to render the HTML. I'd suggest you research how to use [for loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), and also the [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append) method in jQuery

Comment: "no_of_traveler": "2",
        "pack_stat_date: "02/20/2017",
        "pack_final_date: "02/27/2017",
        "package_details_id: "273",
        "promo_discount: "",
        "discount: ""  i want this data like this in table format in html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After parse you can use access property by using .Dot notation. or if you do not like .dot notation you use as below.

Sample version

```
 var obj = JSON.parse(response);
    for(var prop in obj.booking_trip){

      var propvalue = obj.booking_trip[prop];
    $("div").append(propvalue);

    }
```

Full Code

```
 <body>
   <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
       <td>Propery</td>
      <td>Value</td>
      </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
   </table>
   <script type="text/javascript">

  $(function(){

    var json = {
    "booking_trip": {
        "no_of_traveler": "2",
        "pack_stat_date": "02\/20\/2017",
        "pack_final_date": "02\/27\/2017",
        "package_details_id": "273",
        "promo_discount": "",
        "discount": ""
    },
    "price": "5000"


};

var $tbody = $("tbody");
for(var pro in  json.booking_trip ){
 var $row = $("<tr></tr>");
   $row.append($("<td>"+pro+"</td>"));
   $row.append($("<td>"+json.booking_trip[pro]+"</td>"));
   $tbody.append($row);
}

  })
</script>
  </body>
```

Comment: only last value price s appending.i need all the data given below
"no_of_traveler": "2",
        "pack_stat_date: "02/20/2017",
        "pack_final_date: "02/27/2017",
        "package_details_id: "273",
        "promo_discount: "",
        "discount: ""  i want this data like this in table format in html

Comment: Reason only add last value you have access correct property. Like obj.booking_trip I will modify my above code

Comment: Thank you so much Damith Asanka